# Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value' (with Xcode 13.2 and AlamoFire 5.4.3)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to update an app in Xcode 13.2 with AlamoFire 5.4.3, SwiftyJSON 5.0.1.  I was able to get everything working except for the following errors. (Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value')

I'm pretty new with Swift and eager to learn.  The app worked fine when it was using an older versions of AlamoFire.  I didn't write this app originally.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I can clear up anything please let me know.

James

```
class func getPatiens(options: String, completion: @escaping (_ status: Bool, _ message:String, _ patientsList: [PatientEntity]) -> Void) {
        
        let url = Common.getRequestURL(action: "PATIENTS", options: options, index: "")
        
        AF.request(url, method: .get, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch(response.result) {
            
            case .success(_):

               // ERROR: Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'
               if response.result.value != nil{

                // ERROR: Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'
                let jsonResult = JSON(response.result.value as! [String: Any])
                    
                    let patientsList = jsonResult["results"].array!
                    
                    var arrPatients = [PatientEntity]()
                    
                    for index in 0 ..< patientsList.count {
                        let patient = PatientEntity()
                        
                        patient.p_dol  = patientsList[index]["DOL"].string!
                        patient.p_id   = patientsList[index]["ID"].string!
                        patient.p_name = patientsList[index]["NAME"].string!
                        
                        arrPatients.append(patient)
                    }
                    
                    completion(true, "success", arrPatients)
                }
                break
            
            case .failure(_):
                completion(false, "Server Failed", [])
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get rid of SwiftlyJSON and start using Codable

Comment: Which framework is `Result` defined in?

Comment: @AdamPro13 `Result` is a native [generic enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) Swift type

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the info on SwiftyJSON.  The app was written a couple years ago by a contracted developer.  I am trying to see if I can get it up and running with some changes.

Comment: It seems like this code was originally using an older version of Alamofire which defined its own `Result` type. That type did have a `value` property, so it might be best just to extend Swift's `Result` and recreate that property.

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You are receiving a result enumeration. It contains a Success or a Failure. You are ignoring both of them. What you need is to get their associated values:

To get the success `value`:

```
case let .success(value):
```

To get the failure `error`:

```
case let .failure(error):
```